# Writing stories with romance. Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

I love writing stories and I have recently come up with a story which I think sounds great. But I am hesitating a bit since it includes romance between two characters who aren't married. I am not thinking of including 18+ stuff or anything. All I will include is kissing, holding hands etc. = stuff you would see in Disney cartoons really.

I have read that this could be haram, because even if I don't include 18+ stuff, it might still make the readers fantasize about these things even if it isn't my intention to do so.

However, we also have a lot of childrens' movies that include such romance. That doesn't make them haram because it's just fictional?